# Is the offspring between a demon and a celestial possible? If so what is it called and is it in a book somewhere?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, races, forgotten-realms

I have a friend trying to make a hybrid between a celestial and a demon in 5e. I know the Aasimar exists (human/celestial) and I know the Tiefling exists (Human/demon) but what if you cut out the human middle-man. What would this creation be called? Is it RAW?

It seems like an incredible being, but it seems as though it might be really overpowered...

Comment: Related: [This list of all playable races](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77248/35259) so far (assuming we've kept it up to date)

Comment: For what it is worth, an aasimar is not necessarily an offspring of a celestial in 5e. They simply have to have "a touch of the power of Mount Celestia" or be descended from a creature who did. Nor need a tiefling be direct offspring of a demon: one variation of tiefling is the result fo "a pact struck generations ago infus[ing] the essence of Asmodeus—overlord of the Nine Hells—into their bloodline"

Comment: In fact, the direct offspring of a mortal and a demon is typically a Cambion, not a tiefling: "A cambion is the offspring of a fiend (usually a succubus or incubus) and a humanoid (usually a human). " *Monster Manual*

Comment: @DavidCoffron: In prior editions there were mentions of tieflings arising as a result of second-generation demon/devil mating (well, in 2E, Baatezu/Tanar'ri), e.g. 1/4 demon/devil or less, the rest human (Forgotten Realms had a variant species that was elf based IIRC). Either way, the separation in 5E has been addressed [in another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125858/28941).

Comment: There have been "Half-Celestial" and "Half-Fiend" templates in previous editions of D&D.  It seems these only exist as Homebrews in 5e, though I wouldn't know for certain.  You could google search for some examples, and consider applying them to a creature, though you may need additional House Rulings/Exceptions to let you apply them directly to Fiends or Celestials (but not necessarily to Tieflings/Aasimar).

Comment: How would you roleplay a celestial-demon hybrid's character? Would they be Neutral alignment most of the time, or say Neutral Good but have anger management problems?

Comment: A DM who finds the result overpowered can declare that since they are opposed, some of the ancestral effects just cancel out.  Perhaps they have no more inclination in alignment than a human.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### This type of creature is not described in the rules

After sifting through [all of the celestials](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=3&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&sort=cr) and [all of the fiends](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=9&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=), it appears there is no mention of a pair that could procreate in such a way to create a part-celestial/part-fiend individual. You could, however, create such a creature using the Dungeon Master's Toolbox in the Dungeon Master's Guide where it details how to create custom monsters and custom races (both of which could be useful in your friend's endeavor).

### What we can find for celestials

In 5e so far, there are very few celestials mentioned in the rules. Even still, there are some creatures that seem promising. The only celestials that mention a mechanism for reproduction are the Couatl and the Pegasus (both found in the Monster Manual):

Couatl procreation is described as

> ...a beautiful and elaborate dance of magic and light, which results in a gem-like egg from which a new couatl hatches. The parent that sought out the mate raises the newborn couatl and instructs it as to its duties, so that it can complete whatever task the parent leaves unfinished.

I could easily see a fiend that reproduces through infecting the eggs of non-fiends. Such a creature might infect a couatl egg and the resulting creature may share some of the features from the original parents and the infecting fiend.

And the Pegasus entry simply states

> Pegasi mate for life, build their nests in hard-to-reach locations, and give birth to live young.

This is pertinent as a nightmare (a fiendish mount) is created by

> the torturous removal of a pegasus’s wings, driving that noble creature to evil as it is transformed by dark magic.

It is unclear if this nightmare would still be able to reproduce with their former mate, and what would result in such a union (if it were somehow facilitated).

### What we can learn from fiends

There are a number of fiends that are born from the union of fiends and humanoids. Any of these creatures may resulting in semi-celestial origins if the humanoid shared celestial blood. The features of this type of creature (such as whether they remain celestial in any way) are also unclear. You can find a list of humanoid-spawned fiends below:

*MM =* Monster Manual *; VGtM =* Volo's Guide to Monsters

- Night Hag (MM)

  - reproduce through the consumption of human children which later transform into hags
- Draegloth (VGtM)

  - half-drow, half-demon born in an unholy, dangerous ritual
- Barghest (VGtM)

  - born to goblin parents just like normal offspring and develops the ability to assume fiendish form
- Tanarukk (VGtM)

  - corrupt orcish bloodlines for generations upon breeding, bearing them in some female descendants

Using any of these creatures, you may be able to get some guidance into how a part-celestial, part-fiend would come about.

Comment: It's worth noting that celestials and fiends seem capable of 'changing'. The current devil in charge of the blood war is actually a former angel.

Comment: One thing all those creatures have in common is that despite their mixed heritage they still have only one creature type. Infact, to my knowledge there is no officially published creature with two types, hence the creature type of the offspring in question will be either a fiend or a celestial, but not both. The mixed heritage is represented in the statblock with tags and some traits, if anything at all. For example, that Tanarukk is a fiend, but not also a humanoid, it has both demon and orc tags, it has a trait common to demons and a trait common to orcs.

Answer (score 16):

There is not a RAW version of this race in 5e. However, you can use the rules found in the Dungeon Master's Guide (see page 285) to create your own races and subraces.

Answer (score 7):

#### None appear in 5th edition, though it is not intrinsically impossible

There is no creature in D&D 5th edition that represents the offspring of a fiend and a celestial. The offspring of a mortal and fiend or celestial are certainly possible, and earlier answers to this question cover the topic quite well.

However, in earlier editions of the game there was at least one instance of the offspring of two different types of fiends, specifically a demon and a devil. In D&D 3rd edition adventure *Bastion of Broken Souls*:

> The Cathezar is one of Aameuls best agents. She is a fiend, but is an outcast among both demons and devils—she is half demon and half devil, spawn of a doubly unholy union.

The Cathezar has the abilities of both a kyton (chain devil) and marilith demon, suggesting that these were her parents. This suggests that canonically, creatures who are the offspring of two *outsiders* are possible, even among directly opposed enemies, although they would be extremely rare.

Another possibility is that someone might be the distant offspring of, say, an aasimar and a tiefling. There's no rule that says you can't be ⅛ aasimar and ⅛ tiefling; there's just no game statistics to represent that in D&D 5e, so you'd have to invent your own.

Answer (score 7):

## Nephalem (not RAW)

An offspring of a Celestial and a Demon is named a Nephalem, Nephalim or Nephilim in a lot of different universes.

Nephalem is a term heavily used by Blizzard in Diablo where they are human-free. From [a Diablo fan wiki](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Nephalem):

> Nephalem are humanity's forebears. The offspring of angel and demon, their existence would forever alter the balance of power in the Great Conflict.

The Darksider franchise uses the Biblical term *Nephilim*. Per a [Darksiders fan wiki](https://darksiders.fandom.com/wiki/Nephilim):

> Nephilim are an ancient and nearly extinct race born from a union of Angels and Demons engineered by the demoness Lilith when she created the first.

Devil May Cry also uses the Biblical term *Nephilim*. Per a [Devil May Cry fan wiki](https://devilmaycry.fandom.com/wiki/Nephilim):

> The Nephilim are a race of hybrid beings within DmC: Devil May Cry continuity. They are the offspring of angels and demons; and are thus considered "the third race".

The term is common enough to be present in [the homebrew part of D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/1504-nephalem):

> Aasimar are the descendants of celestials just as tieflings are to infernal beings. Nephalem are both. The result of the unholy union of Tiefling and Aasimar, Nephalem have both fiendish and celestial blood running through their veins. They are torn by a desire for good and justice, and resentment toward societies which shunned them. Many are rejected by one if not both parents, and forced to walk their path alone.

The [Wikipedia article on Nephilim in popular culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephilim_in_popular_culture) has more information.

Comment: Please note that official material from *Races of Faerun* disagrees with the homebrew paragraph quoted in the answer. The offspring of an aasimar and tiefling is not either an aasimar or a tiefling.

Answer (score 5):

#### Generic Lore

Since this is a lore question, I would like to add a few relevant examples of beings from D&D which have celestial and fiendish properties:

- **Forlarren** are creatures which initially appeared in the 1e *Fiend Folio*. There, they were described as "the descendents of the offspring of a good nymph and the greater devil who enslaved her". Forlarren were revisited in 5e *Mordenkainen's Fiendish Folio, Volume 1: Monsters Malevolent and Benign*. Not really a celestial-demon hybrid, but still a fey-fiend one.
- In 3/3.5e, there were templates that you could apply to creatures to give them certain properties. 3.5e SRD has templates for [half-fiend](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfFiend.htm) and [half-celestial](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfCelestial.htm). While these templates have mutually exclusive alignment requirements, this did not stop WotC from proposing Memonor, a **half-fiend/half-astral deva**, in a web article titled *[Creatures That Cannot Be](https://web.archive.org/web/20130531121413/http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/eo/20060407a)*.
- In 3.5e *Monster Manual IV*, there is a kind of neutral outsider (a denizen of the Outer Planes) called the **Concordant Killer**. While they are not direct offsprings of celestials and fiends, and the ecology section of the text leaves their origin open to speculation, the main text describes CKs as:

  > ... resembles a tall, scarlet-skinned fiend with a pair of dusky feathered wings. ... Possessing both celestial and demonic heritage, these powerful entities are dispassionate killers who frequently deliver the wrath of the gods. ... This creature is neither wholly fiendish nor celestial but possessed of both natures.

#### Forgotten Realms Lore

Since you have associated the question with the Forgotten Realms campaign setting, you might find the following information from the 3.5e *Races of Faerûn* (page 112) relevant:

> The child of an outsider and another creature is a half-fiend, half-celestial, or half-elemental. If one of these half-blooded creatures has offspring with a humanoid, the result is usually a planetouched creature. The offspring of two planetouched is always a planetouched. Mixed-heritage planetouched of this sort take after one or the other parent (seemingly equal chances) but carry the traits of the other parent, which may show up in their own children.

The first sentence of this text is somewhat open to interpretation, but it reads like the offspring would either be a half-celestial or a half-fiend (both described in the SRD as mentioned earlier), and not both. And if we are talking about the offsprings of further descendants, again, they **will not exhibit mixed characteristics**. For example if an aasimar and a tiefling had offspring, the offspring would either be an aasimar or a tiefling.

#### A Limited 5e Answer: Fallen Aasimar

Not exactly what you are asking for, but since you have mentioned the aasimar, it might be worth reminding that 5e *Volo's Guide to Monsters* offers "fallen aasimar" as a character race, with the following description (page 105):

> An aasimar who was touched by dark powers as a youth or who turns to evil in early adulthood can become one of the fallen - a group of aasimar whose inner light has been replaced by shadow.

I hope all this lore would provide enough fuel for you to homebrew in your campaign.